# How to manually choose cellular network provider?

Tags: windows-10-mobile, cellular

I have no service. Friend recommended me to manually choose which operator I want to connect to. Is it possible on Windows Phone 10?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow these steps:
Settings > Network & Wireless > Cellular & SIM > Click on 'SIM settings under category SIM > Click on 'Search for networks' under category Cellular network > Wait for the searching and then select the operator you want.